# Passing a session variable acrosss two JSP pages

Tags: jsp, session, http-headers

I have two distinct JSP web apps utilising Spring MVC, each one sitting on a separate tab of my application.

One of the JSP web apps has a Java Class that extracts a database variable for a user.

In first.jsp I set the session variable - this is fine and displays the variable correctly.

```
  <c:set var="mySchool" value="${sc}" scope="session" />
```

In second.jsp I want to retrieve the session variable ${mySchool} and I am using the following JTSL code:

```
 <c:out value="${sessionScope.mySchool}" />
```

However the second.jsp is not displaying the variable. I am obviously misunderstanding the way session variables are handled for a single browser session across two tabs.

How do I determine that the session variable is actually being passed in the HTTP headers to see if it is passing between the two tabs?

Comment: your code seems to be fine, try printing session id and see if your jsps are using the same session.

Comment: Yes - I have just checked and both web apps produce identical session Id's.